# Can't import a test license to SharePoint farm or O365 with Utility.ImportAppLicense method

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365-apps

I try to import a test license to SharePoint with Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.ImportAppLicense method, but it always failed. When I try to import the license with a user client context, it always get the following error:

```
using (ClientContext context = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
{
    Utility.ImportAppLicense(context, licenseToken, "en-US", "US", appName, iconUrl, providerName, 5);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

> [ServerException: Sorry, we can't seem to connect to the SharePoint
>   Store. Try again in a bit.]   
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream
>   responseStream) +2058   
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse() +948   
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder
>   sb) +623    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
>   +47    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery() +89    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() +495    O365TestLicenseManagerWeb.LicenseManager.Import(String
>   licenseToken, String appName, String iconUrl, String providerName) in
>   C:\tfs\O365TestLicenseManager\Main\Source\ACS\O365TestLicenseManager\O365TestLicenseManagerWeb\LicenseManager.cs:24
>     
>   O365TestLicenseManagerWeb.Controllers.LicenseController.ImportFile()
>   in
>   C:\tfs\O365TestLicenseManager\Main\Source\ACS\O365TestLicenseManager\O365TestLicenseManagerWeb\Controllers\LicenseController.cs:28
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61   
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14   
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157   
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10   
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncRescyf01ult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9   
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9765121    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

But if I try to import the test license with a app only client context, it will get following error.

```
using (ClientContext context = spContext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost())
{
    Utility.ImportAppLicense(context, licenseToken, "en-US", "US", appName, iconUrl, providerName, 5);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

> [ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied. You do not have
>   permission to perform this action or access this resource.]   
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream
>   responseStream) +2058   
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse() +948   
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder
>   sb) +623    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
>   +47    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery() +89    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() +495    O365TestLicenseManagerWeb.LicenseManager.Import(String
>   licenseToken, String appName, String iconUrl, String providerName) in
>   C:\tfs\O365TestLicenseManager\Main\Source\ACS\O365TestLicenseManager\O365TestLicenseManagerWeb\LicenseManager.cs:24
>     
>   O365TestLicenseManagerWeb.Controllers.LicenseController.ImportFile()
>   in
>   C:\tfs\O365TestLicenseManager\Main\Source\ACS\O365TestLicenseManager\O365TestLicenseManagerWeb\Controllers\LicenseController.cs:28
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61   
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14   
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157   
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10   
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29   
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9   
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9765121    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: I finally found the reason, becasue I passed an incorrect license token to the method.